# JQuery FullCalendar maximum data fullcalendar can hold

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I try to make schedule with fullcalendar with data from database
But when data reach more than 199 calendar not shown, when data limit to 199 calendar shown again.

Is there a max amount of data that a fullcalendar can hold? it seems to crash after 199 data.

my code

```
$('#calendarIO').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,add_event'
        },
        // eventOrder: "time",
        firstDay: 0,
        defaultDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        handleWindowResize: true,  
        eventOrder: "time",
        editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position
                editDropResize(event);
            },
            eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur
                editDropResize(event);
            },
            eventClick: function(event, element)
            {
                detail(event);
                editData(event);
                deleteData(event);
            },
            
            events: JSON.parse(get_data),
            eventRender: function(event, element)
            { 
                element.find('.fc-title').prepend(event.starttime + "-" + event.endtime + " ");

            },
            displayEventTime: false
        });
```

Problem not from fullcalendar but from data at my database

Thank You

Comment: I don't believe there's a set limit, other than the amount of data the client PC is able to render performantly. I'd strongly suggest you find a better way to handle this limitation. I can't think of a reason you'd need to display 200+ events in a calendar - and especially not have it look like an unusable mess in the UI. I'd suggest you limit the calendar by date, or limit the number of events which can be shown, or find a way to group them better. Any of those will work, it's just a case of what works best for your situation.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific limit either. Did you get an error in the browser console or anything when this crash occurs? P.S. I also agree with Rory that 200+ events is way to many for a usable UI, no human can reasonably be expected to absorb or filter that amount of information at once, it would be very difficult to find anything.

Comment: P.S. If you're having performance issues, consider also upgrading to the newest fullCalendar, they have done a lot of work on performance. For one thing, it's no longer implemented as jQuery plugin, which helped to speed it up a lot. The version you appear to be using is now several years out of date.